# How can I use Azure app services to mitigate against growing retention costs?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-plans

I need to devise a pricing strategy for a SaaS product I plan to go live with, as tricky a task as that is.

Putting product 'value' and things like RoI aside (since they're off-topic here), I'm looking for some assurances against a situation whereby my competitively priced product incurs losses because of increasing blob storage/SQL costs in Azure.

In a nutshell, this web app will allow users to create tasks, to which they may attach any number of hi-res images, documents etc.

So, in order to keep this question specific and technical, what services does the Azure platform offer that helps mitigate against escalating costs of data/blob storage? Or which services lend itself to managing these losses/costs?

For example, I *think* a DTU option for my SQL Server will be a flat rate as opposed to a dynamically priced VCore alternative. So I could opt for DTU so I at least know where I stand.

### Question/s

Does Azure offer flat rate services for storage? Would IaaS instead of PaaS give me this?
Does Azure ofer flat rate for SQL Server? (Is my understanding of DTU correct?)

Comment: not sure what you really have in mind for this "Does Azure offer flat rate services for storage?" Storage is always billed as pay-per-use. There is no "store unlimited amount of data for x $".  But why don't you just give each user a limited quota of storage they can occupy and whenever they want to upload something through your app, you check if they have reached your quota yet.

Comment: @silent - thanks for your reply. I'm not expecting "store unlimited" but if, for example, IaaS offered a store up to X for X amount (fixed price) per month, that would help me with the pricing strategy. With regards to charging per use, it's an option, but a strong preference of mine is that I can offer nice, clear pricing options to customers. I'm following suit with the likes of how jira do it.

Comment: What you do offer your customers does not need to have anything to do with what Azure charges you. Say, you charge customer $10 per month to store 100 GB of data. Azure Blob costs you about $2 per month - if they actually store 100GB. If they store less, you pay less to Azure, so more profit for you. You only need to ensure that they don't upload more then what you grant them

Comment: I get that, it's a valid point - and in most cases it's a viable pricing strategy, but X amount of GB means very little to my potential customers and costing it up (which I'll be helping them with) becomes a bit murky, since it depends on usage. I like the clarity of how jira offers pricing but, again, I'm failing to see how they've controlled this based on the fact you can upload any arbitrary amount of attachments to jira tickets.

Comment: I'll be honest, you have me thinking more about this charge per data now. My question still remains, how is it commercially viable to charge for a SaaS product when this opens up the floor for 'excessive' use - and how can Azure help with this. But for this particular product I'm keen to explore this £ per GB here. Thanks.